# Kafka Connector doesn't importing or exporting

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm trying to follow the tutorial on the main page of Apache Kafka (http://kafka.apache.org/quickstart#quickstart_kafkaconnec) but when I get to the part of import and export with Kafka Connect I create the file:

```
echo -e "foo\nbar" > test.txt
```

and i run the command for initialice the Connectors:

```
bin/connect-standalone.sh config/connect-standalone.properties config/connect-file-source.properties config/connect-file-sink.properties
```

But nothing happend. No message was sended. Even the file "test.sink.txt" doens't appear.

I check the files: connect-file-source and connect-file-sink and these look good:

```
name=local-file-source
connector.class=FileStreamSource
tasks.max=1
file=test.txt
topic=connect-test
```

And:

```
name=local-file-sink
connector.class=FileStreamSink
tasks.max=1
file=test.sink.txt
topics=connect-test
```

When I run:

```
bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic connect-test --from-beginning
```

To see the messages, doesn't display nothing just this:

```
jonathangomez$ bin/kafka-console-consumer.sh --bootstrap-server localhost:9092 --topic connect-test --from-beginning
[2018-10-03 01:19:42,901] WARN [Consumer clientId=consumer-1, groupId=console-consumer-30141] 1 partitions have leader brokers without a matching listener, including [connect-test-0] (org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient)
```

But the Topic "connect-test" appear in the list of Topics with:

```
bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181
```

The result look like this:

```
jonathangomez$ bin/kafka-topics.sh --list --zookeeper localhost:2181    
__consumer_offsets
connect-test
my-replicated-topic
pageviews
test
users
```

I'm running this commands on a macOS Sierra 10.12.6 and Apache Kafka 2.11-2.0.0.

Comment: Are there are any error logs from standalone-connect?

Comment: Nop :T Where errors are displayed? On the Kafka server logs window? Because I don't see any error

Comment: What do you mean `connect-standalone.properties` remains empty? By default, it shouldn't be empty.

Comment: When you run `bin/connect-standalone.sh` it should produce output, which are its logs. Can you check for any errors in these logs. You might want to also try using an absolute path, e.g. `/tmp/test.txt` in case the file you're creating is in a different location from which Connect is reading.

Comment: `leader brokers without a matching listener`... Did you edit the server properties at all?

Comment: My bad, the file have content but running `bin/connect-standalone.sh` don't show me any log... don't show me nothing.